# Angular: erro em modelo com listagem de objetos

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-6, model

Eu tenho esses 2 modelos, sendo que o livro tem uma listagem de objetos do tipo linguagem.

```
Model book
import { Language} from "./language";
export class Book {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    language: Array<Language>;
}

Model language
export class Language{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

Quando tento criar o objeto livro e adicionar uma linguagem na sua listagem de linguagens, tenho erro de undefined:

myBook: Book();
myLanguage: Language();

hello() {
    this.myLanguage = new Language();
    this.myLanguage.id = 1;
    this.myLanguage.name = "portuguese";

    this.myBook = new Book();
    this.myBook.id = 1;
    this.myBook.name = "one book";
    this.myBook.language.push(this.myLanguage); //error - undefined
}
```

Necessitaria de algum tipo diferente de declaração para essa listagem?

Obrigada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes do `push`, associe um array vazio para `language`:

```
this.myBook.language = [];
this.myBook.language.push(this.myLanguage);
```

Comment: Era isso, obrigada !